# Error Gradle version 2.10

Tags: android

I got and error with Android studio 2.0 preview 4

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in App/myfolder/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

I have already change the the distributionUrl but still above error is show up, here is my setting on `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

And here is my app `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.craftedinbali.edy.cdbu"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.1'
}
```

EDITED

And here is my project `gradle.build`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
     jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Go to File->Settings...
Menu "Build,Execution,Deployment"->"Build Tools"->"Gradle"
And Check "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)"

You can also click CTRL+ALT+S to open the settings menu. If you can't find the gradle section, just seach "gradle" in the search text box situated on the top of the settings window

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank for your nice answer...but I could get that menu, can you help me with screenshot :)

Comment: I can go to Gradle setting but I can not found "Use default gradle wrapper" checkbox?? Can you help me with screenshot?? and I used mac not widnows so the shortcode is not work for me, sorry...thanks

Answer (score 2):

Right click your project, click "Open Module Settings"

[image]

Then Click "Project" and set Gradle version to 2.10

[image]

Gradle will now build with Gradle 2.10

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer, I check my Gradle is already set to 2.10, but still I got the error...