# Need 2.8 gradle instead of 2.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get this error while running Android Studio:

*Warning:Gradle version 2.8 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Git\SC-Wallet-Android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.8-all.zip*

I changed the link to the proper one but Android Studio, automatically creates .gradle folder in Users folder where i can locate 2.4 version of gradle(2.8 is created aswell) if i delete 2.4 folder, when application is launched 2.4 is created again. What creates this version?

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in .gradle are created by gradle itself. This indicates that you are still not running gradle 2.8 but 2.4 instead.

Make sure Android Studio is configured to use the gradle wrapper. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35010828/1796579) for instructions.